# Angular2 integration testing, how to test a child component that calls its parent's method in its template

Tags: angular, testing, integration-testing

I have a child component that has events in its template such as:

```
child.html 
<a (click)="parent.onClick()"></a>
```

Normally when I go about testing events in angular2, I would do something like:

```
 child.spec.ts
      it('', () => {
            let menu = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('a');
            menu.click();
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(something)
        });
```

with setup that looks something like:

```
 BeforeEach(async(() => {
                TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                    declarations: [ChildComponent]
                    providers: [ParentComponent]
                    })
                    .compileComponents();
```

But in the case of the calling the parent's method in the child's template, the .click(); never calls the parent's method. If I move the logic into the child component, the test will of course work, however, I was wondering if there was way to test the click event as it is currently setup.

Comment: I find it incorrect to reach the parent's `onClick()` method honestly...
You should try to do it differently and establish a correct communication between your components, and test things through that. 
Normally, you never need to provide your `ParentComponent`.

Try to be more precise about what is your aim and what the `OnClick()` method does, maybe it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read up in the official documentation for cross-component communication. There are several ways to accomplish what you are looking for. Up to you to study and find out which one matches your use-case.
[Angular.io - component-interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)